# apticron, apt-get dist-upgrade and aptitude

Tags: debian, aptitude

I'm confused, on my debian server I've gotten the daily "updates available" message by apticron. I normally then just use aptitude to install the upgrades. Today I got a message which shows two upgrades. But they don't show up in aptitude.
When I do a `apt-get dist-upgrade` they show up as "NEW" packages to be installed. `aptitude dist-upgrade` seems to ignore them.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how to get rid of the messages (It doesn't seem like I really need the new packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although apticron invites you to use aptitude to upgrade your system, internally it uses apt. As they use different resolvers and have their own configurations, sometimes there are differences in their results.

I see 3 ways to get rid of the messages:

- Install the packages

Or

- In `/etc/apticron/apticron.conf`, decomments the line

  `#DIFF_ONLY="1"`

  to receive email only with upgrades since the last run.

Or

- Using dpkg, puts on hold the packages apt wants to install. For example:

  `# echo libc6 hold | dpkg --set-selections`

  apt won't propose you to upgrade libc6 anymore, but aptitude will.

Comment: I decided to just install the packages. They are not usefull to me, but they don't hurt either.